# Select rows based on whether value of a columns is in top X of columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe which I want to subset depending on whether a value in a certain column is among the top 5 values of all the columns in that row.
This is a simplified version of my dataframe:

```
> my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10,5), b= rnorm(10,5), c=rnorm(10,5), d=rnorm(10,5), e=rnorm(10,5))
> my.df
          a        b        c        d        e
1  6.401462 5.318849 5.373496 5.101140 3.710973
2  6.715845 4.786936 3.521965 4.264029 4.525138
3  6.076211 5.356114 5.605134 5.443002 5.296778
4  7.009623 5.275595 4.801874 4.355892 6.752737
5  5.002059 6.163398 6.063694 2.409702 6.172111
6  6.298305 3.291884 5.737053 4.701320 4.752406
7  4.856246 4.674743 5.550828 7.501786 5.466611
8  5.037990 4.129333 4.797334 5.143915 5.558161
9  4.903592 3.135622 5.879798 5.639893 4.368915
10 5.500374 4.400130 3.980433 6.203259 4.498614
```

Now I want only the rows where the values of column a or column b are among the top 2 values in their row. So in this example deleting row 7-9, giving:

```
          a        b        c        d        e
1  6.401462 5.318849 5.373496 5.101140 3.710973
2  6.715845 4.786936 3.521965 4.264029 4.525138
3  6.076211 5.356114 5.605134 5.443002 5.296778
4  7.009623 5.275595 4.801874 4.355892 6.752737
5  5.002059 6.163398 6.063694 2.409702 6.172111
6  6.298305 3.291884 5.737053 4.701320 4.752406
10 5.500374 4.400130 3.980433 6.203259 4.498614
```

Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, initially I was testing on the data without the `set.seed`.  Have to change it to `decreasing = TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the rows with `apply` (from `base R`) check whether `any` of the elements in 'a' or 'b' are `%in%` the `sort`ed group to create a logical index and subset the rows based on that

```
i1 <- apply(my.df, 1, function(x) any(x[1:2] %in% sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]))
my.df[i1,]
#         a        b        c        d        e
#1  6.401462 5.318849 5.373496 5.101140 3.710973
#2  6.715845 4.786936 3.521965 4.264029 4.525138
#3  6.076211 5.356114 5.605134 5.443002 5.296778
#4  7.009623 5.275595 4.801874 4.355892 6.752737
#5  5.002059 6.163398 6.063694 2.409702 6.172111
#6  6.298305 3.291884 5.737053 4.701320 4.752406
#10 5.500374 4.400130 3.980433 6.203259 4.498614
```

---

Or use `max.col` from `base R` to create the logical index and that would be much faster and avoid any transformation

```
i1 <- max.col(my.df, "first")
i2 <- max.col(replace(my.df, cbind(seq_len(nrow(my.df)), i1), -Inf), "first")
my.df[(i1 %in% 1:2) | (i2 %in% 1:2), ]
```

#### data

```
my.df <- structure(list(a = c(6.401462, 6.715845, 6.076211, 7.009623, 
5.002059, 6.298305, 4.856246, 5.03799, 4.903592, 5.500374), b = c(5.318849, 
4.786936, 5.356114, 5.275595, 6.163398, 3.291884, 4.674743, 4.129333, 
3.135622, 4.40013), c = c(5.373496, 3.521965, 5.605134, 4.801874, 
6.063694, 5.737053, 5.550828, 4.797334, 5.879798, 3.980433), 
    d = c(5.10114, 4.264029, 5.443002, 4.355892, 2.409702, 4.70132, 
    7.501786, 5.143915, 5.639893, 6.203259), e = c(3.710973, 
    4.525138, 5.296778, 6.752737, 6.172111, 4.752406, 5.466611, 
    5.558161, 4.368915, 4.498614)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, but is it possible to specify columns based on column name instead of column 1 and column 2?

Comment: @joffie  Yes, you ca replace the `x[1:2]` with `x[c("a", "b")]`

Comment: @akrun your `max.col` suggestion looks a bit wrong, also logically

Comment: @akrun I guess you meant `+1` at the end of the second line instead of `-1`, but either way, dropping the first column does not drop the max values so you won't necessarily find second-largest values like this

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` possibility. We create row_index using `row_number` and convert the dataframe to long format (`gather`), grouping by `row` we `filter` the groups which has top 2 values either "a" or "b" and convert the data back to wide format(`spread`).

```
library(tidyverse)

my.df %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   gather(key, value, -row) %>%
   group_by(row) %>%
   filter(any(key[order(value, decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]] %in% c("a", "b"))) %>%
   spread(key, value)

#    row     a     b     c     d     e
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  6.40  5.32  5.37  5.10  3.71
#2     2  6.72  4.79  3.52  4.26  4.53
#3     3  6.08  5.36  5.61  5.44  5.30
#4     4  7.01  5.28  4.80  4.36  6.75
#5     5  5.00  6.16  6.06  2.41  6.17
#6     6  6.30  3.29  5.74  4.70  4.75
#7    10  5.50  4.40  3.98  6.20  4.50
```

I have intentionally kept the `row` column so that we know that row 7-9 is deleted, if it is not needed we can remove it by using `ungroup() %>% select(-row)`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all rows and check for each row wheter `1` or `2` is in the first two indexes of the `order`ed values:

```
my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10,5), b= rnorm(10,5), c=rnorm(10,5), d=rnorm(10,5), e=rnorm(10,5))
my.df <- my.df[sapply(1:nrow(my.df), function(x){any(c(1, 2) %in% order(my.df[x, ], decreasing = TRUE)[1:2])}),]
```

With example data:

```
set.seed(1)
my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10,5), b= rnorm(10,5), c=rnorm(10,5), d=rnorm(10,5), e=rnorm(10,5))
my.df

          a        b        c        d        e
1  4.373546 6.511781 5.918977 6.358680 4.835476
2  5.183643 5.389843 5.782136 4.897212 4.746638
3  4.164371 4.378759 5.074565 5.387672 5.696963
4  6.595281 2.785300 3.010648 4.946195 5.556663
5  5.329508 6.124931 5.619826 3.622940 4.311244
6  4.179532 4.955066 4.943871 4.585005 4.292505
7  5.487429 4.983810 4.844204 4.605710 5.364582
8  5.738325 5.943836 3.529248 4.940687 5.768533
9  5.575781 5.821221 4.521850 6.100025 4.887654
10 4.694612 5.593901 5.417942 5.763176 5.881108
```

Rows `3` and `10` should be removed:

```
my.df <- my.df[sapply(1:nrow(my.df), function(x){any(c(1, 2) %in% order(my.df[x, ], decreasing = TRUE)[1:2])}),]
my.df

         a        b        c        d        e
1 4.373546 6.511781 5.918977 6.358680 4.835476
2 5.183643 5.389843 5.782136 4.897212 4.746638
4 6.595281 2.785300 3.010648 4.946195 5.556663
5 5.329508 6.124931 5.619826 3.622940 4.311244
6 4.179532 4.955066 4.943871 4.585005 4.292505
7 5.487429 4.983810 4.844204 4.605710 5.364582
8 5.738325 5.943836 3.529248 4.940687 5.768533
9 5.575781 5.821221 4.521850 6.100025 4.887654
```

Answer (score 1):

I attach you a `data.table` based solution:

```
library(data.table)
my.df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10,5), b= rnorm(10,5), c=rnorm(10,5), d=rnorm(10,5), e=rnorm(10,5))
my.df <- as.data.table(my.df)
my.df[my.df[,(sum(a<=.SD)<=2) | (sum(b<=.SD)<=2), by=seq_len(nrow(my.df))]$V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I went for the following solution. You add 2 columns telling which position the value of column a and b are. Then you subset based on those values.

```
my.df$a.num <- as.numeric("") 
my.df$b.num <- as.numeric("") 


for (i in 1:nrow(my.df)){
  index <- sort(my.df[i,], decreasing = TRUE)
  a.num <- which(colnames(index) == "a")
  b.num <- which(colnames(index) == "b")
  my.df$a.num[i] <- LA
  my.df$b.num[i] <- LV}

my.df <- my.df[my.df$a.num < 3 | my.df$b.num < 3, ]
```